# jsoup remove div with a certain class

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a list in `jsoup` like this:

```
Elements tbody = new Elements();
```

`tbody` might look like this (`----` separates elements in `tbody` list):

```
<td> 
 <div data-emission="56b2140adb6da7bf3cbf6228" class="mainCell"> 
  <a href="/tv/weather-country-12457/"> <span class="left">16:00</span> 
   <div> 
    <p>Weather - country</p> 
   </div> </a> 
 </div> 
 <div data-emission="56b2140adb6da7bf3cbf6237" class="mainCell shows pending"> 
  <a href="/shows/that's-70-show-550347/epi1201/"> <span class="left">16:10</span> 
   <div> 
    <p>That's 70 show</p> 
    <span class="info">epi. 1201, Show</span> 
   </div> <p class="onAir"> <span>Pending</span> <u></u> <u style="width: 5%"></u> </p> </a> 
 </div> </td>
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <td> 
 <div data-emission="56b23876db6da7bf3cbf6588" class="mainCell pending"> 
  <a href="/tv/weather-563806/"> <span class="left">16:10</span> 
   <div> 
    <p>Weather</p> 
   </div> <p class="onAir"> <span>Pending</span> <u></u> <u style="width: 51%"></u> </p> </a> 
 </div> 
 <div data-emission="56b23876db6da7bf3cbf6589" class="mainCell"> 
  <a href="/tv/animal-cops-2615/"> <span class="left">16:15</span> 
   <div> 
    <p>Animal Cops</p> 
    <span class="info">epi. 3079, Show</span> 
   </div> </a> 
 </div> 
 <div data-emission="56b23876db6da7bf3cbf658a" class="mainCell shows"> 
  <a href="/show/house-md-1601/odc137/"> <span class="left">16:30</span> 
   <div> 
    <p>House MD</p> 
    <span class="info">epi. 137, Show</span> 
   </div> </a> 
 </div> </td>
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <td> 
 <div data-emission="56b213b3db6da7bf3cbf61a1" class="mainCell movies pending"> 
  <a href="/movie/star-trek-564170/"> <span class="left">16:00</span> 
   <div> 
    <p>Star Trek</p> 
    <span class="info">Movie</span> 
    <span class="szh prem">| Premiere</span> 
   </div> <p class="onAir"> <span>Pending</span> <u></u> <u style="width: 21%"></u> </p> </a> 
 </div> </td>
```

My goal is to remove every movie/show that is pending/onAir. So in this example i would like to get rid of a whole `div` that has:

- `that's 70 show`
- `weather`
- `star trek`

f.e:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tbody.size(); i++){
            tbody.get(i).select("div").select("p").select(".onAir").remove();
        }
```

It removes only an element itself, not a whole `div`. I have tried in many ways but unsuccessfully. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the pending shows also carry the `pending` css class. If this is true for all cases you can do it very simply by:

```
doc.select("td>div.pending").remove();
```

This will remove all `div` elements with the `pending` class from the document doc. if they are direct children of a `td` element.

Alternatively, you can use your approach and filter for the `p` element with the correct `onAir` class and inner text:

```
doc.select("td>div:has(p.onAir:contains(Pending))").remove();
```

See the [CSS selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to understand the power of Jsoup.

Comment: does `div.pending` refer to f.e. this `<div data-emission="56b2140adb6da7bf3cbf6237" class="mainCell shows pending">` ? So I don't have to use full name like `mainCell shows pending` but `pending` insted ?

Comment: In HTML you can give an element more than one class by separating each class name by a space. Than means the div element carries 3 classes, one of which is called pending. You can select elements of a class by using the dot operator followed by the class name: `.pending`. You may concatenate selectors if you need to select more than one class at the same time: `.pending.mainCell` would select only elements that carry both classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code snippet.

```
Elements mainCells = tbody.select("div.mainCell");
for(int i = 0; i < mainCells.size(); i++){
    Elements mainCellsP = mainCells.get(i).select("div").select("a").select("p");
    if (mainCellsP.size() == 2) {
        // Remove this node from DOM tree
        mainCells.get(i).remove();
    }
}
```

First select the appropriate node you want to delete and then call [remove()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#remove--) method of that node.